# INSERT INTO prepared statements, PHP MYSQL, optimising a lot of columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Please help me to understand how to optimize mysql queries in php. When you have a lot of columns, prepared statement looks like

```
$inst = $db->prepare("insert into year_$year (user_name,type_of_day,month_row,day_1,day_2,day_3,day_4,day_5,day_6,day_7,day_8,day_9,
day_10,day_11,day_12,day_13,day_14,day_15,day_16,day_17,day_18,day_19,day_20,day_21,day_22,day_23,day_24,day_25,day_26,day_27,day_28,day_29,day_30,day_31)
values
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$inst->execute($chunk_post[$init]);
```

this code is from here: http://govnokod.ru/php?page=356
where people ridicule shitty codes.

I do not understand how to do it in other way.

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? What problems come up?

Comment: Please, please, please, read about `database normalisation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A little Joke:**

u can use `for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; i++) {}` to construct your Query ;)

**The Reality:**

Read about Database Normalization here: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Your Ultimate goal should be the third normal form.

You should think about some Day which are linked to one Month.

think about a table `month` and table `day`.

Read about `SQL JOIN`.

Sure, you will not have the DataType `DateTime`?

This Question is **way to broad** to give you a solution instead of an *learn here*, *learn there* answer. Your Question is about basics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PDO](https://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

In this case even if you have many fields, you can recognize the fields without confusion.

Answer (score 0):

there is option to use dibi library and use it this way:

```
$query = dibi::query("SELECT ...
FROM p... -- comment
WHERE p.id = %i
AND p.lang = %i", $id, 1);
        $raw = $query -> fetchAll();
        foreach($raw as $n => $row) {
            array_push($output, Array('p_id' => $row['p'],//comment
                'p_w' => $row['p2']

            ));
        }
```